# matplotlib の凡例の表示について

Tags: python, matplotlib

matplotlib のpyplotで一つのグラフに複数の折れ線グラフを表示させるにあたり、凡例の付し方についてご教示賜りたいと存じます。

今、複数の折れ線は、一つの変数に保存されており、一回のpyplotで描画できるものとします。その時、凡例の付し方がわかりません。

以下の例は、三角関数の正弦関数と余弦関数を一度に表示させる例ですが、この時凡例をどのように付したらよいでしょうか。(labelの引数をどのようにしたらよいのかわかりませんでした)

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1,10,100)

y1 = np.sin(x).reshape(-1, 1)
y2 = np.cos(x).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.concatenate([y1, y2], axis = 1)

plt.plot(x, y, label = )
plt.legend()
```

ネットを調べても、ばらばらにpyplotを描画し、その都度labelを引数として指定する例はあるのですが、一回で凡例を表示させる例は見つかりませんでした。

Comment: 参考: [How do I assign multiple labels at once in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11486074)

Answer (score 1):

metropolis氏に掲載いただいた参照先で解決いたしました。ありがとうございます。

概要といたしましては、複数の折れ線グラフそれぞれを変数に保存し、それに対応するラベルをplt.legend内で対応させるように見受けられました。

Milla Well　という方の投稿から、以下、引用です。

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from numpy.random import *

a = rand(4,4)
a
>>> array([[ 0.33562406,  0.96967617,  0.69730654,  0.46542408],
   [ 0.85707323,  0.37398595,  0.82455736,  0.72127002],
   [ 0.19530943,  0.4376796 ,  0.62653007,  0.77490795],
   [ 0.97362944,  0.42720348,  0.45379479,  0.75714877]])

[b,c,d,e] = plot(a)
legend([b,c,d,e], ["b","c","d","e"], loc=1)
show()
```